# Cython recursive struct declarations

Tags: cython

I'm trying to use a C struct in Cython, that defines a linked list:

```
typedef struct {  
    struct query_result* next_result;  
    char*                result;   
} query_result;
```

As you can see I'm using the query_result type inside its own definition.
Using this as is, in Cython gives me compiler errors:

```
cdef extern from 'c_wrapper.h':  
    struct query_result:  
        struct query_result* 
        char*
```

Any ideas about how to properly handle this recursive definition in Cython?

Comment: Please use code blocks.  Indent your code with four spaces and SO will turn it into code.

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't use the `struct` keyword when you are referring to the type:

```
cdef extern from 'c_wrapper.h':  
    struct query_result:  
        query_result* more
        char* data
```