# Recursion on a python list, using cython?

Tags: python, list, cython

I am trying to use cython to possibly speed up a recursive function which performs numpy look ups to find a connected region of interest:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
DTYPE = np.int
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t

def find_ob(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] ar, list point, list s):
    if ar[point[0], point[1]] == 1:
        s.append(point)
        px = point[0]
        py = point[1]
        new_points = [[px-1, py], [px, py-1], [px+1, py], [px, py+1], 
                      [px+1, py+1], [px-1, py-1]]
        for i in new_points:
            if i not in s:
                find_ob(ar, i, s)

# From python:
ar = np.zeros((15, 15), dtype=int)
ar[2:8, 2:8] = 1

s = []
cythonmodule.find_ob(ar, point, s)
print len(s)
>>> 36
```

However, I think I am passing around a native python list and so am not getting any speedup. Do I need to convert the python list to a c array or struct or something before passing into find_ob? I have seen this: [Cython recursive struct declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774364/cython-recursive-struct-declarations) but not sure what to do.

Comment: Recursion is always slower than Iterations

Comment: Change `s` into a set, this should make things notably faster: `s = set()`, Then `s.add(point)`, instead of `s.append(..)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are appending to a list in your recursion: `s.append(point)`, which is inefficient no matter whether you are working with C arrays (because you would have to allocate a new array of size old array + 1, copy old array over and add one element) or python lists.

Then you are searching a list here: `if i not in s:` which means that for every point i, the whole list is going to be traversed to check if i is in that list. You should use a set (or in C ideally an unordered map).

In fact you have accelerated with C the fastest operation in your code, your bottleneck seems to be:

```
for i in new_points:
        if i not in s:
            find_ob(ar, i, s)
```

I think you can get more out of your code in python first by changing the datastructures used. Then if you want to go to the c route, make sure you are never doing operations on python lists.

Comment: Thanks, changing to sets results in 8x speed up!